# Problem loading models with modules in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have a folder structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbxtQ.jpg) and I'm trying to load the `News` model inside my controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * Login
 */
class Admin_NewsController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function preDispatch() {
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
        $layout->setLayout('admin');
    }
    public function init() {
        $this->db = new Application_Admin_Model_DbTable_News();
    }

    public function indexAction() {

    }

    public function addAction() {
        //$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();
        // Calls the Request object
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            // Retrieves form data
            $data = array(
                "new_title" => $request->getParam('txtTitle'),
                "new_text" => htmlentities($request->getParam('txtNews')),
                "new_image" => $request->getParam('upName'),
                "new_published" => 1
            );
            // Inserts in the database
            if ($this->db->addNews($data)) {
                $this->view->output = 1;
            } else {
                $this->view->output = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $this->view->output = 0;
        }

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    }
}
```

And my **model**:

```
<?php

class Application_Admin_Model_DbTable_News extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'news';

    public function addNews($data) {
        $this->insert($data);
    }
}
```

Althoug I'm getting this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your News class belongs to the module, its name should be `Admin_Model_DbTable_News`, without `Application_` prefix.

See more on autoloading within modules at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module

Comment: ok, but now it says `Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_DbTable_News' not found`

Comment: Do I have to use some autoloader?

Comment: The only thing you need to make sure is that your module bootstrap is extending Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap as in:


class News_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap